# Show an image/icon for a drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I recently bought an external hdd(WD Elements), when I connected it to my pc, the drive shows up in **Computer**, but it showed, instead of the default icon for a drive, the logo of Western Digital. Then I partioned the drive to three partitions and none of them carries the logo. No, I do not want the logo back, but, I would like to show another image as the icon for the drives. How can I do this?

Comment: [How to Change a Drive Icon in Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/65828-drive-icon-change.html)

Comment: Duplicate, indeed! I just checked the question. I could not find it by google search, so I posted a question. Shall I delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

On the drive you want a custom icon, you have to have 2 items on the root of the drive

1. An icon image file of the image you want to use
2. a text file called "autorun.inf", inside the text file you need the following text

```
[Autorun]
Icon=My custom image.ico
Label=whatever label you want
```

Icon= must reflect the exact name of the icon image file on the drive.

There are several websites that will convert most any image file to an icon file for free

http://www.prodraw.net/favicon/

.

Comment: What is "label" then?

Comment: I would stick to formatfactory, it can convert  images to icon format

Comment: Label is the name of the drive you wish to make it, same as a volume label for a hard drive.